# Angular my child component doesn't take css from his container

Tags: css, angular

I have a container which contains 3 mat-card. The container has a class, which applies styles depending on whether the div is the first or the last child.
I created 3 component, one per div. My child components take the css of the parent.

CSS still applies, except for &: last-child and &: first-child

Before, in my HTML parent (works) :

```
<div class="conteneur">
<mat-card class="first_or_last_child">first</mat-card>
<mat-card class="first_or_last_child">second</mat-card>
<mat-card class="first_or_last_child">third</mat-card>
</div>
```

After, with my child component (partially works) :

```
<div class="conteneur">
<app-child-first></app-child-first>
<app-child-second></app-child-second>
<app-child-third></app-child-third>
</div>
```

In the HTML of my child component :
`<mat-card class="first_or_last_child">first</mat-card>`

I tried to apply class to child component, it's better, but it don't take the entire place :

```
<div class="conteneur">
<app-child-first class="first_or_last_child"></app-child-first>
<app-child-second class="first_or_last_child"></app-child-second>
<app-child-third class="first_or_last_child"></app-child-third>
</div>
```

My entire CSS :

```
.first_or_last_child {
  width: 28%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  min-width: 276px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;

  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);

  mat-list {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  mat-card-header {
    margin: -16px -16px 0 -16px;
    background-color: #004196;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 24px 4px;

    ::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    mat-card-title {
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;

      span {
        color: #FFED00;
      }
    }

    mat-card-subtitle {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
    }
  }

  mat-list-item {
    ::ng-deep {
      .mat-list-item-content {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
      }

      img {
        width: 40px;
      }

      .title {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 16px;
        flex-direction: column;

        span:last-child {
          color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);
          font-size: 13px;
          margin-top: 4px;
        }
      }

      .check-icon {
        margin-left: auto;
        color: #4CAF50;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please add your folder struncture?

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou, did it. I'm sorry, it's a big CSS, and the real HTML is bigger too, I hope someone can help me in principle without having to change all the CSS

Comment: @shadowman_93 I'm sorry, I don't see why the folder struncture is necessary ? and which folder struncture : parent and childs components, my HTML with div, mat-card...?

Comment: I just want to see your folders are in the right places and want to see how do you import them to angular components. For example `styleUrls: ['./hero-app.component.css']` part.

Comment: @Lainea What do you mean with: _it's better, but it doesn't take the entire place_ ? Is the length wrong?

Comment: @shadowman_93 my CSS is applied, the problem is really with first-child, last-child

I have parent.component.ts with ```styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']```
And I have child-component.ts with ```styleUrls: ['../parent.component.css']```
(it's not their real name)

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou I see differences when I applied the class on the called component : but it's not what I want. I don't know where the problem comes from. Maybe applying the class on the component call fixed my last child problem, and I see another problem ...
This is the principle that interests me, how do I manage the first and last children on the CSS side when I want to display components?

Comment: @Lainea does your CSS apply to your components or is it an inheritance problem? Sorry, I don't quite understand what your problem is.

Comment: Could you please add this code after your css import line, `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou I'm sorry, It's hard to explain without show you the entire HTML & CSS. But I don't want to have problem with my job, it's because I can't show this details.
Thank you to try to help me !

Comment: @shadowman_93 nothing's change, thank you to try to help me - I will read all line of my CSS, and try to understand where the problem is. I close this ticket